# Spring - task execution with delayed return

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have one service, eg.

```
public boolean registerNewUser(...) {
  getEntityManager().performSteps(...);
  return true;
}
```

to create a new user.

Now I have the requirement that the execution of the method should be delayed for about `2000 ms`. I would like to have it that way, that a timer starts at the method entry than executes the required steps and `return` but returning not before `2000 ms` have been elapsed.

The `@Scheduled`-annotation does not really fit and - to be honest - I do not know how to use the `@Async` annotation to achieve it.

Is it required to code it manually or are there some specific Spring annotations which allow me to *simply* configure the requirement?

Comment: What exactly is your requirement and for what purpose? Slowing down the execution of code is not a very common requirement, that is I doubt that you will find any out-of-the-box solution for this. Simply adding `Thread.sleep(2000)` is not working for you? If not, why?

Comment: `Thread.sleep` would be ... but since I do not really know the universe of Spring - I have no clue if there are some other config-options.

Comment: If your requirement really is that you method call must take at least 2 seconds, then `Thread.sleep(2000)` is probably the way to go.

Comment: Is this an attempt to implement rate limiting?  If so there may be better options, such as intercepting this at the HTTP/servlet level and sending HTTP 429 (too many requests) on subsequent registration attempts if not enough time has passed since the last.  Bozho has a post about this here: https://techblog.bozho.net/basic-api-rate-limiting/.  Using a sleep in your domain logic has the opposite effect than is usually desired for rate limiting: it causes your HTTP thread pool to become saturated while not preventing simultaneous requests.

Comment: Note I think Bozho incorrectly dismisses Guava's implementation when he says `tryAcquire` is blocking.  It's synchronized to make it threadsafe yes, but nothing blocking is synchronized on the same mutex.